# How to find the total number of columns in a table in teradata?

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I am trying to get the number of columns in a row for a given table in teradata. I am finding it difficult to find the total number with the usual SQL command. This is what I have tried but did not give me any result:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_catalog = 'WMS' 
   AND table_name = 'RM_SELLER_ITEM_MST'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*INFORMATION_SCHEMA* is not implemented in Teradata, the *DBC* database holds metadata:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM dbc.ColumnsV
 WHERE DatabaseName = 'WMS' 
   AND TableName = 'RM_SELLER_ITEM_MST'
```